# Why would a identity be true if elements on both side are linear and the identity is true for basis of vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation, linear-transformations

[image]

$$(v \wedge u )\wedge w= (u\cdot w)v-(v\cdot w)u$$

$\wedge$ is the cross product.
My book justifies this identity by "First we observe that both sides are linear in u,v,w; thus, the identity will be true if it holds for all basis vectors"

1)I don't understand how both sides are linear in u ,v ,w.

2)Why would both sides being linear for u , v ,w imply that we only need to check for basis.

I can't think of a better way to phrase this question such that it would be easier to search for others. If you have suggestions put them in the comments.

Comment: The LHS is trilinear (i.e. linear in each of u, v and w) because $\land$ is bilinear. The RHS is trilinear because he inner product and [scalar multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_multiplication) are bilinear. If an $n$-linear map (here: the difference LHS-RHS) is $0$ on the ($n$-tuples of) basis vectors then it is  $0$ on every ($n$-tuple of) vectors, [precisely by multilinearity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilinear_map#Properties).

Comment: I don't understand why people are voting to close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We make a map which is equal to $RHS - LHS$ of the equation.

$f(u,v,w)=(u\wedge v)\wedge w -(u \cdot w)v +(v \cdot w)u$

This is a multilinear map. If we change any one of the input variables while keeping others constant it behaves as a linear map. This is because cross product , dot product and scalar multiplication are bilinear.

So $(u\wedge v)\wedge w$ , $(u \cdot w)v$ , $(v \cdot w)u$ all are trilinear .

Why is this the case?
If g and h are both bilinear then for $cx+a$

$g(h(cx+a,y),z) =g(ch(x,y)+h(a,y),z)=cg(h(x,y),z)+g(h(a,y),z)$

It would be similarly linear for y . So g is trilinear .

Since all three functions have input variables u , v ,w and are trilinear any linear combination of the functions would also be trilinear.

Hence $f(u,v,w)$ is trilinear.

We show $f(e_1,e_1,e_1)$ ,$f(e_2,e_1,e_1)$ ,$f(e_3,e_1,e_1)$,$f(e_1,e_2,e_1)$ ,$f(e_2,e_2,e_1)$...  are zero by evaluation. There is some symmetry in $f(u,v,w)$ so we probably don't need to show they are zero for all 27 possible combinations.

Every $f(u,v,w)$ can be shown to be to be made from linear combination of those functions.
$f(u,v,w) =a_1f(e_1,v,w)+b_1f(e_2,v,w)+c_1f(e_3,v,w)$

$f(e_1,v,w)=a_2f(e_1,e_1,w)+b_2f(e_1,e_2,w)+c_2f(e_1,e_3,w)$...

As $f(u,v,w)$ is made of linear combinations of zero vector.
We get $f(u,v,w)=0$ and LHS=RHS.

This is the closest I have got to what author was referring to.
Thanks [@Anne Bauval](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/386889/anne-bauval) for the comment.

If you think author was going for a simpler proof or know how to formally show we don't need to calculate all 27 possibilities  , put your thoughts in the comments.